# Gatsby running as a local file (index.html) without a server

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, gatsby

Using the [starter gatsby site](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/quick-start/), when I build it and load `/public/index.html` in chrome without running `gatsby serve` - none of the route links work. They point to the root of my drive - so `<Link>`'s look like this `file://c:/page-2`

I tried setting the `pathPrefix` in `gatsby-config.js` and ran a `gatsby build --prefix-paths` - but I can't get the route `<Link>`'s to be relative.

```
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: `/`,
....
```

Any ideas? I know this is possible with `create-react-app` without a server - as long as you set `"homepage": "./"` in `package.json` and use `HashRouter` -  but not sure how to achieve the same in Gatsby.

Comment: Try running `gatsby serve` or using a simple http server from the directory

Comment: The whole point is not to use `gatsby serve` - I just want to load index.html in the browser

Comment: Then you can use Live Server extension in VS Code

Comment: I need to put it on a network fileserver and have users be able to have the route links to different routes work, running a VS Code server extension doesn't' seem like the right answer for this unique use case. The route links just need to be setup properly and I'm not sure how to do that. Like I was trying to say above , it's possible with CRA but I can't figure it out with Gatsby.

Comment: Gatsby performs serverSide rendering and hence all its pages need to be served from a live server. The Routing for pages isn't really on client side in gatsby. You could probably create a simpleHttpServer and open index.html from there and see if it works

Comment: "Instead of purely server-side rendering, Gatsby uses the same APIs to create static HTML at build time when you use gatsby build. Gatsby-rendered HTML pages give you the SEO and social sharing advantages of server-side rendering with the speed and security of a static site generator."

Comment: @Ryan were you able to find a workaround?